# Prove that the solution set of $a_n \not= n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is finite.

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

Problem:For fixed positive integers $s, t$, define $a_n$ as the following.
$a_1 = s, a_2 = t$, and $\forall n \ge 1$, $a_{n+2} = \lfloor \sqrt{a_n+(n+2)a_{n+1}+2008} \rfloor$.
Prove that the solution set of $a_n \not= n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is finite.

I have try prove $a_{n}\ge n$,We already know $a_3 \ge 3$ and $a_4 \ge 4$.
We prove by induction that $a_n \ge n$ for all $n\ge 3$.
Assume that $a_n \ge n$ and $a_{n+1} \ge n+1$. 
Then 
$$(a_{n+2}+1)^2 > a_n + (n+2)a_{n+1} +2008 \ge n+(n+2)(n+1) + 2008 > (n+2)^2$$, so $a_{n+2} \ge n+2$.
Therefore, we have $a_n \ge n$ for $n \ge 3$.then I can't Thanks

Comment: just by curiosity, where did you get this question from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A_n=\max\{a_n;a_{n+1}\}$

**Lemma 1**. $a_n \ge n$ for all $n \ge 2008$. You already proved this lemma.

**Lemma 2**. $A_n \ge n$ for all $n \ge 2008$.
**Proof**. Since $A_n \ge a_n$ and $a_n \ge n$ then  $A_n \ge n$.

**Lemma 3**. There is $n_0 \ge 2008$ such that $A_{n_0} \le n_0+1$. **Proof by contradiction**. Assume that $A_n \ge n+2$ for all $n \ge 2008$. Then $a_{n+2} \le \sqrt{a_n+(n+2)a_{n+1}+2008}\le \sqrt{A_n+(n+2)A_{n}+2008} \le\sqrt{A_n+A_{n}^2+2008}=$ $=\sqrt{(A_n+0.5)^2+2007.75}<A_n+0.5+\frac{2007.75}{2(A_n+0.5)}\le A_n+0.5+\frac{2007.75}{2(2008+0.5)}<A_n+1$. Then $a_{n+2} \le A_n$ for all $n \ge 2008$. Since $a_{n+2} \le A_n$ and $a_{n+1} \le A_n$ (by definition of $A_n$) then $\max\{a_{n+1};a_{n+2}\} \le A_n$. Then $A_{n+1}\le A_n$ for all $n \ge 2008$. Then $A_{n}\le A_{2008}$ for all $n \ge 2008$. But $A_n \ge n$. Contradiction.

**Lemma 4**. $a_{n+2} \le A_n+1$ for all $n \ge 2008$. **Proof**. If $n \ge 2008$ then $a_{n+2} \le \sqrt{a_n+a_{n+1}+(n+1)a_{n+1}+2008}\le\sqrt{a_n+a_{n+1}+a_{n+1}^2+2008} \le \sqrt{2A_n+A_{n}^2+2008}=$ $=\sqrt{(A_{n}+1)^2+2007}<A_n+1+\frac{2007}{2(A_n+1)}\le A_n+1+\frac{2007}{2(2008+1)}<A_n+1.5$. Then $a_{n+2} \le A_n+1$ for all $n \ge 2008$.

**Lemma 5**. $a_{n+k} \le A_n+k-1$ for all $n\ge 2008$ and for all $k \ge 1$. **Proof by induction**. It is true for $k=1$ by definition of $A_n$. It is true for $k=2$ by Lemma $4$. Assume that $a_{n+k} \le A_n+k-1$ and $a_{n+k+1} \le A_n+k$. Then by Lemma $4$ we have $a_{n+k+2}\le A_{n+k}+1=\max\{a_{n+k};a_{n+k+1}\}+1\le \max\{A_n+k-1;A_n+k\}+1=$ $=A_n+k+1$.

**Lema 6**. There is $m\ge 2009$ such that $a_n=n$ for all $n\ge m$. **Proof**. By Lemma $5$ we have $a_{n_0+k} \le A_{n_0}+k-1$ for all $k \ge 1$. But by Lemma $3$  $A_{n_0} \le n_0+1$. Then $a_{n_0+k} \le n_0+1+k-1=n_0+k$ for all $k \ge 1$. But $a_{n_0+k} \ge n_0+k$ by Lemma $1$. Then $a_{n_0+k}=n_0+k$ for all $k \ge 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n > 20080$ (large enough).

Let $ b_n = a_n - n$.
We want to show that for some $N$, for any $ n > N$, $ b_n = 0 $.

**Claim:** $b_{n+2} \leq \frac{ b_{n+1} + \frac{2b_{n+1} + b_n + 2010 } { 20080 }} {2}    $

> **Proof:** $ (a_{n+2})^2 \leq n + b_n + (n+2)(n+ 1+b_{n+1}) + 2008 $
>  $= n^2 + n (4 + b_{n+1} ) + 2b_{n+1} + b_n + 2010 $
>  $ < n^2 + n (4 + b_{n+1} + \frac{ 2b_{n+1} + b_n + 2010 } { 20080 }) $
>  $< ( n + 2+\frac{b_{n+1} + \frac{ 2b_{n+1} + b_n + 2010 } { 20080 }} {2} )^2 $

**Corollary:** There is an $N_1$ such that for any $n \geq N_1$, $b_n \leq 0$.

Given that you've shown $ b_n \geq 0$, we conclude that for $ n > N$, $b_n = 0$.

Comment: Hello,we have prove $a_{n}\ge n,\forall n\in N$,why have $a_{m}=m-1<m?$

Comment: Oh, I misread...

Comment: @functionsug Alright, this ended up being a "just do it" problem, so you should really show your work / do it yourself.

Comment: Hello, I think there is an $N_{1}$,such that for any $n\ge N_{1}$ $b_{n}\le 0$,is not $n\ge N$?.and why? because this sequence $b_{n}$ is decreaing?

Comment: Mistake. You write $n+b_n+(n+2)(n+1+b_{n+1})+2008<n^2+n(4+b_{n+1}+\frac{b_n+2008}{20080}) \Leftrightarrow$ $2010+b_n+2b_{n+1}<\frac{n}{20080}(b_n+2008)$. Let $n=20081$. Then you inequality $2+2b_{20082}<\frac{1}{10}(1+\frac{b_{20081}}{2008})$. 
This is not true.

Comment: @functionsug Based on the claim, $b_{n}$ decreases very quickly. E.g. If you have $b_N = 8, b_{N+1} = 8$, then $b_{N+2} <5 , b_{N+3} < 3, b_{N+4} < 2, b_{N+5}  < 1$.

Comment: @Witold It's not a double implication. It's just one way. All I'm using is $ 1 < \frac{ n}{2008 0 } $ (and multiplying that to the constant coefficient $b_n + 2008$). The approach is similar to your lemma 4, so I'm confused about why you think it is incorrect. EDIT: Ah, I missed some terms. I've edited it, and it should be fine now.